# I don't understand why I get [ngForm] is not a know property of element form and [ngClass] is not a known property of input

Tags: angular

I have this code, using Angular 14, which in a HUGE app for a customer I'm working for.

The standard imports are as follows then the top section of the .html page

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, AbstractControl, NgForm, Validators, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpService } from "../../../services/http.service";
import { CookieService } from "ngx-cookie-service";
import { MatDialog } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { MatSnackBar } from "@angular/material/snack-bar";
import { SavedataService } from "../../../services/savedata.service";
import { DateValidator } from "src/app/modules/shared/components/date-validator/date-validator.component";
import { Regx } from "src/assets/regex";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
```

```
<form id="adminForm" [formGroup]="adminForm">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-12-marginTopAdjust">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-6-adjust">

.....
```

and

```
                <input id="dateEntered" type="date" name="dateReceived" formControlName="dateReceived"
                  class="form-control inputdata" minlength="14" maxlength="14" data-title="Date Received"
                  (blur)="blurEventMethod($event)" placeholder="00/00/0000" (disabled)=true [pattern]="regNoPattern"
                  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': ontabout && f['dateReceived'].errors }" />
                <div
                  *ngIf="submitted || f['dateReceived'].errors || f['dateReceived'].touched || f['dateReceived'].invalid"
                  class="required">
                  <span *ngIf="f['dateReceived'].errors && f['dateReceived'].errors['required']"
                    class="text-danger required">
                    {{getErrorMessage('dateReceived', 'Date Received ')}}
                  </span>
                </div>
```

So here's my question:

Even with everything imported correctly in app.module.ts, as it should, why would only 3 or 4 pages (.html) generate this error when the 100s of other HTML pages, have no issues?

The page in question is in the same line as the other folders under app/components/...

It won't compile...

Do I need to delete it, regenerate the component?

This happens with  components and  components, just a teeny number of them.  I'm dumbfounded.

[image]

Comment: Are you importing FormsModule into the module containing this component?

Comment: FormsModule is definitely inside app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you have already done this

Import FormsModule and/or ReactiveFormsModule into your module.

Then issue happens sometimes as the vscode fails to locate your module file. Please restart vscode and your system and it'll be gone.

Answer (score 0):

You need revisited concept: you **never** import in .html else in the .ts file

Angular group several elements: class, directives, interfaces,services, components.. in "packages". This "packages" are known as "modules", e.g `@angular/core`, `@angular/forms`.

We can also create a serie of elements and group them in [modules](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules).

To use a component, directive,... in another component we need

1. import the element in our .ts file
2. Our component should belong to a module (unless you use standalone
   components) that import a module where the component, directive
   belong

e.g. we want to use FormsGroup in our FormComponent

The formComponent belong to a module main.module.ts

*main.module.ts*

```
//import the necessary Modules
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

//import the components
import { FormsComponents} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ], //<--here the modules
  declarations: [ FormComponent], //<--here the Components
})
export class MyModule { }
```

*Our component*

```
import { FormsGroup,FormsControl } from '@angular/forms'; //<--see that import the "directive"
                                                          //NOT any Module

@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './form.component.css' ]
})
export class FormComponent{
  form=new FormGroup({
     id:new FomControl()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by actually restarting VS Code, updating it, reopening it, then adding the following in my  tag and on the .ts file:

```
<form id="theForm" ngForm #TheForm [formGroup]="theForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(theForm, $event)">
```

in the .ts file...

```
  @ViewChild('TheForm') TheForm!: NgForm;

  theForm!: FormGroup;
```

And the issue went away